# Unable to get oAuth token for BigCommerce once click app

Tags: php, api, plugins, oauth, bigcommerce

I am a complete noob to BigCommerce as well as plugins. And recently planned to develop a one click app which could be installed by the users of any store on their store. I have good hand on php. So, i can code but dont know the flow for plugins.
To create a draft app i went to devtools.bigcommerce.com and created an app defined Auth Callback url as https://amanangira.com/bCommerce/oauth.php
and Load Callback url as https://amanangira.com/bCommerce/callBack.php

in oauth.php i inserted the following code

```
<?php

$data = array( "client_id" => "123456789",
                "client_secret" => "123456789",
                "redirect_uri" => "https://amanangira.com/bCommerce/callBack.php",
                "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
                "code" => $_GET["code"], "scope" => $_REQUEST["scope"], "context" => $_GET["context"], );

$postfields = http_build_query($data);

$ch = curl_init();
//$url = "https://api.bigcommerce.com/stores/wky4s3lfef/v3/";
$url = "https://login.bigcommerce.com/oauth2/token";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

$obj = json_decode($output);

var_dump($obj); 
?>
```

Now whenever i install the app in my test store it says following.

> /var/www/html/angira/bCommerce/oauth.php:37:
>   object(stdClass)[3]
>     public 'error' => string 'redirect_uri_mismatch' (length=21)
>     public 'error_description' => string 'Parameter redirect_uri does not match registered URI' (length=52)

Please help with the above in as much as simple terms. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

After some hit and trials and i finally stumbled upon the solution. Which was to update the redirect_uri in the oauth.php to that which was the Auth Callback uri in the application configuration.

```
"redirect_uri" => "https://amanangira.com/bCommerce/oauth.php"
```